# using angular $http.post will not post to file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, post

With the code below I keep getting a 404 error. the hello.json file is in the root and I can access it in the browser since it is at localhost:3000/hello.json
not too sure what I did wrong and why this wont write and just returns a 404 not found error.
on click of the button(in the html) that runs the update function I get the alert with the error callback.

```
angular.module('seakrat')                                                       
     .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) { 
        $scope.update = function(course){ 
              $http.post("/hello.json", {hello: "there"})                         
                  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {              
                          alert('nailed it')                                      
                            })                                                   
                  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {                
                          alert(data + status);                                   
                          });                                                     
              $scope.course = '';                                                 
         };                                                                       
    }]);
```

Comment: I'd speculate you are using a server side framework that requires you to explicitly specify the HTTP method in its routes, but you've not given us a lot of information about your server side set up to go on.

Comment: What do you expect POSTING to a static json file to accomplish?

Comment: look in the console. What url is it hitting? Try to type the url in a browser to get a match without using angular

Comment: apparently post doesn't do what I had hoped it did. :(

Comment: @Sam the URL is fine, it opens the JSON I thought the post would append the object to the end of the specified file

Comment: Imagine for a moment if it did do that. The internet would essentially be useless, because anyone, anywhere, could replace your index.html with their own html.

Comment: I mean, wouldnt I just be appending all the index.htmls on the internet? If I had write access.

Comment: Right, but, giving "write access" to a client would of course require something on the server to *give* said access, such as a node.js webserver that is expecting a POST to that path. that would of course work, assuming you had code in place that would interpret that post and write to the json file.

Answer (score 1):

You *cannot* write to a file using `angularJS`, its a client side framework. You need to have a *serverside language* to do this job.

Comment: thanks, guess I have more googling to do in order to build this thing.